# SQL Syntax error in ASP

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am making some slides for a PowerPoint presentation that loops infinitely. I have two slides that i have been tasked with. one shows the number of students within certain brackets for GPA, [Screenshot of The Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYfgt.png), which works fine

The Second Is A graph that show the Average GPA of each class (7-12) intended to look like [Average GPA Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfXdH.png)

The code Is in HTML, but uses ASP to query a SQL server to pull data to bused to make a graph formed with [Canvas JS][3]

Here is my first Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- #include virtual="/includeit/dbfunc.asp" -->

<%
 set oConn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
 set oRS = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
 
 call open_connection
%>

<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 title:{
  text: "High School GPA Brackets (MP1)"
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column",
  indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
  indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
  dataPoints: [
<%
 sSQL = "SELECT count (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as StudentCount " &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN " &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID " &_
   "Where CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA >= 3.7 and Cadets.CurrentGrade >= 9"
   
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "3.7 + " & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("StudentCount") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("StudentCount") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT count (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as StudentCount " &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN " &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID " &_
   "Where CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA >= 3.5 and CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA < 3.7 and Cadets.CurrentGrade >= 9"
  
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "3.5 - 3.7" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("StudentCount") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("StudentCount") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT count (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as StudentCount " &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN " &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID " &_
   "Where CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA >= 3 and CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA < 3.5 and Cadets.CurrentGrade >= 9"
  
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "3.0 - 3.5" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("StudentCount") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("StudentCount") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT count (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as StudentCount " &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN " &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID " &_
   "Where CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA >= 2.5 and CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA < 3 and Cadets.CurrentGrade >= 9"
  
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "2.5 - 3.0" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("StudentCount") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("StudentCount") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
 
 sSQL = "SELECT count (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as StudentCount " &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN " &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID " &_
   "Where CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA >= 2 and CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA < 2.5 and Cadets.CurrentGrade >= 9"
  
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "2.0 - 2.5" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("StudentCount") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("StudentCount") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT count (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as StudentCount " &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN " &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID " &_
   "Where CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA >= 1.5 and CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA < 2 and Cadets.CurrentGrade >= 9"
  
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "1.5 - 2.0" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("StudentCount") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("StudentCount") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
  sSQL = "SELECT count (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as StudentCount " &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN " &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID " &_
   "Where CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA <= 1.5 and Cadets.CurrentGrade >= 9"
  
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "Less than 1.5" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("StudentCount") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("StudentCount") & chr(34) & " } " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
  oConn.close
     
    set oRS = nothing
    set oConn = nothing
%>

  ]
 }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/inc/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p align=center>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 98%; width: 98%;">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works as intended a displays the information in the first screen shot

The second is *exactly* the same, except for a different select statement (which I have tested and know for a fact works) and title.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- #include virtual="/includeit/dbfunc.asp" -->

<%
 set oConn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
 set oRS = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
 
 call open_connection
%>

<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 title:{
  text: "Average GPA by Class"
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column",
  indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
  indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
  dataPoints: [
<%
 sSQL = "SELECT AVG (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as AverageGPA" &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN" &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID" &_
   "Where Cadets.Active = 1 and Cadets.CurrentGrade = 7"
   
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "7" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("AverageGPA") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("AverageGPA") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT AVG (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as AverageGPA" &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN" &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID" &_
   "Where Cadets.Active = 1 and Cadets.CurrentGrade = 8"
   
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "8" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("AverageGPA") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("AverageGPA") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT AVG (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as AverageGPA" &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN" &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID" &_
   "Where Cadets.Active = 1 and Cadets.CurrentGrade = 9"
   
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "9" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("AverageGPA") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("AverageGPA") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT AVG (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as AverageGPA" &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN" &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID" &_
   "Where Cadets.Active = 1 and Cadets.CurrentGrade = 10"
   
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "10" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("AverageGPA") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("AverageGPA") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT AVG (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as AverageGPA" &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN" &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID" &_
   "Where Cadets.Active = 1 and Cadets.CurrentGrade = 11"
   
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "11" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("AverageGPA") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("AverageGPA") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
 sSQL = "SELECT AVG (CadetGPAs.WeightedGPA) as AverageGPA" &_
   "FROM CadetGPAs INNER JOIN" &_
   "Cadets ON CadetGPAs.PropertyID = Cadets.PropertyID" &_
   "Where Cadets.Active = 1 and Cadets.CurrentGrade >= 12"
   
  oRS.open SSQL, oConn
   response.write("{ label: " & chr(34) & "12" & chr(34) & ", y: " & oRS("AverageGPA") & ", indexLabel: " & chr(34) & oRS("AverageGPA") & chr(34) & " }, " & vbcrlf)
  oRS.close
  
  oConn.close
   set oRS = nothing
   set oConn = nothing
%>

  ]
 }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/inc/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p align=center>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 98%; width: 98%;">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will not even draw the graph, and I cannot figure out for the life of me what is happening.

The source code it returns is

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>


<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 title:{
  text: "Average GPA by Class"
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column",
  indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
  indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
  dataPoints: [
 <font face="Arial" size=2>
<p>Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers</font> <font face="Arial" size=2>error '80040e14'</font>
<p>
<font face="Arial" size=2>[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'CadetGPAs'.</font>
<p>
<font face="Arial" size=2>/Grice/AVGPA.asp</font><font face="Arial" size=2>, line 32</font>
```

But the Datapoints section is supposed to be more like

```html
data: [{
  type: "column",
  indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
  indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
  dataPoints: [
   { label : "7", y: 3, indexLabel: "3" },
   { label : "8", y: 2.7, indexLabel: "2.7" },
   { label : "9", y: 4, indexLabel: "4" },
   { label : "10", y: 2, indexLabel: "2" },
   { label : "11", y: 1.5, indexLabel: "1.5" },
   { label : "12", y: 4.3, indexLabel: "4.3" }
```

Which the somewhere within the ASP is not outputting the information for the datapoints

Comment: Looks like a missing space behind your "Inner Join"

Comment: Seems that all of second example's query strings missed single space before `&_` as in first example. Try adding every single space before end of each part of concatenated query string.